# How to uninstall collectd completely from ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, collectd

I had collectd-5.5 installed on my ubuntu-16.04 server and I tried to install the newer version as described in [collectd download page.](https://collectd.org/download.shtml).
it seems that it didn't work, so now I'm trying to uninstall collectd from my server completely, to install a fresh version again.

To uninstall, I've run below commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove collectd
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove collectd
sudo apt-get purge collectd
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove collectd
```

now when I delete the `/var/lib/collectd` folder, it gets created immediately with the `rrd` folder in it.

collectd command and service do not exist anymore, but it seems that it's not removed from my server completely, or maybe I have another version of collectd running?

how can I check?
did I miss something in the uninstalling process?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly the server-process is still running. Did you try to restart the computer after deinstallation and then delete the folder?

Comment: No, unfortunately, this is a production server and I can't restart it, but thanks for the point, I check to see if the process is still running then I can kill it.

Comment: Did you follow the guide before uninstalling (the ` apt-get remove ...` commands) the ubuntu version or after? Also did you install the newer version via the tar.bz2-file or the ubuntu/debian specific way?

Comment: @Lutz, the process was still running and that was the reason, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Lutz mentioned in question comments, the collectd process was running after the uninstall, so I had to kill it manually, restarting the server would do the work though, but in my case, I was working on a production server, so I decided to kill it this way:

```
sudo killall collectd
```